# How to program in rom?

Tags: c, microcontroller

**char a[1000];//it is accepted by the controller
whereas declaring char a[2000]; means it shows no space...**

**whereas using const char a[6000];//it is accepted the compiler doesn't displayed error it is executed**

Anyone please explain about it..

Comment: i am using pic18f4550, it contains 2KRAM, and 32K ROM..

Comment: Don't update your question in comment, update your question directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables without `const` *must* be placed in RAM, because they are mutable.

Variables with `const` can be placed in ROM (Flash or EEPROM typically) because they cannot be changed.

It seems that your microcontroller haven't got enough RAM memory for `char a[2000];`, and that's why it fails. Remeber that you need to have RAM memory for stack also.

Comment: Then define array with `const`, and there should be no problem. If I understood your question, it works fine already.

Comment: @BkFrancis Or did you mean you *must*  be able to modify values? In that case you need to have bigger chip or better algorith.

Comment: @BkFrancis Unfortunately I cannot answer that, because I don't know details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: ok finr thanks for this info... i want to use the rom space for my project to store the values at run time... for 10 seconds it gives nearly 3000 values.. and i have to store those values in the rom space, since i got very less amount of space in ram..

Comment: @BkFrancis In that case I would use small buffer in RAM, and then save values to ROM when buffer gets full.